# How to return a List of students that study more than two subjects in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following data schema and minimal data records, I need to formulate a query to show students that study more than two subjects.

TABLES IN SQL SERVER

```
create table Estudiante 
(
id int primary key not null,
nombre varchar(50)
)

insert into Estudiante (id, nombre)
values
('1','Maria'),
('2','Juan'),
('3','Yarlin'),
('4','Ana'),
('5','Marcos'),
('6','Juana'),
('7','Esther'),
('8','Luisa')

create table Materia 
(
id int primary key not null,
nombre varchar(50),
estado varchar(10)
)

insert into Materia (id, nombre, estado)
values
('1','Filosofía','activo'),
('2','Bases de datos','activo'),
('3','Programación','activo'),
('4','Literatura','activo'),
('5','Teología','activo')


create table MateriaProfesor 
(
id int primary key not null,
idMateria int foreign key references Materia,
idProfesor int foreign key references Profesor
)

insert into MateriaProfesor (id, idMateria, idProfesor)
values
('11','2','1'),
('12','1','2'),
('13','2','1'),
('14','3','4'),
('15','4','3'),
('16','5','2')

create table MateriaEstudiante 
(
id int primary key not null,
idMateria int foreign key references Materia(id),
idEstudiate int foreign key references Estudiante(id),
Fecha date
)

insert into MateriaEstudiante (id, idMateria, idEstudiate, Fecha)
values
('20','4','3','10/11/2017'),
('21','5','2','10/11/2017'),
('22','3','8','10/11/2017'),
('23','5','4','11/11/2017'),
('24','1','5','11/11/2017'),
('25','1','3','11/11/2017')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the free code writing site. Please share what you have tried so far for this requirement. Also please post your expected output. `SQL Server` <> `MySQL`. You are tagged with MySQL but in the post you are mentioned the tables in SQL Server. Please correct the tag or content

Comment: This looks more like MySQL than sql server, and store data using the correct data type in each case

Answer (score 0):

Try to analysis the question step by step:

1. list all of students, means `GROUP BY`
2. that study, means `FROM StudentCourses LEFT JOIN Students ON 
   StudentCourse.StudentID = Students.StudentID`
3. more than 2 subject, means `where count(...) > 2`

PS. 1. Use English. 2. think yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and given information, I come up with this query.

```
SELECT estudiante.nombre, COUNT(materia.nombre) FROM `estudiante`
INNER JOIN materiaestudiante ON materiaestudiante.idEstudiate = estudiante.id
INNER JOIN materia ON materia.id = materiaestudiante.idMateria
GROUP BY estudiante.nombre
HAVING COUNT(materia.nombre) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The table definition seems to use Non-English language words. And
   since you have not translated which table is representing what
   entity/operation, so I am going to do guesswork here in terms of
   understanding of the tables. My guesses:

   Estudiante = Student
   nombre = name

   Materia = Subject
   estado = status

   MateriaEstudiante = SubjectStudentEnrollment
   Fecha = No idea what date it is, so ignoring it's use

   2. **With the above guesses, and with the limited given explanation of the
      details of the problem**, here is the quick query:

   ```
   ;WITH CTE AS
   (
        SELECT   E.id
                 ,E.nombre
                 ,SubCount = COUNT(ME.idMateria)
        FROM     MateriaEstudiante ME
                 INNER JOIN Estudiante E      
                   ON ME.idEstudiate = E.id
        GROUP    BY
                 E.id
                 ,E.nombre
        HAVING   COUNT(ME.idMateria) > 2
   )
   SELECT nombre
   FROM   CTE;
   ```

Note:- Using inner join, because you need Student information and hence any row in MateriaEstudiante with NULL StudentId are not relevant for you.